# Gradient not applying to full view on larger screen

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uiview, uikit

I implement a code to apply diagonal gradient to different views. it worked fine for all small views and all views on small screens but on iPhone 13 Pro Max simulator it doesn't apply to full view and leaves some part to the right side. I only noticed even in some other views which are wider this gradient only applies about 80% in width.
Here's the screenshot how its showing in one view:

[image]

It does not apply to right of the view and the right corner radius is invisible.
Here's the code for Gradient:

```
func applyGradientDiagonal(isVertical: Bool, colorArray: [UIColor]) {
        layer.sublayers?.filter({ $0 is CAGradientLayer }).forEach({ $0.removeFromSuperlayer() })

        let gradientLayer = CAGradientLayer()
        gradientLayer.colors = colorArray.map({ $0.cgColor })
        if isVertical {
            //top to bottom
            gradientLayer.locations = [0.0, 1.0]
        } else {
            //left to right
            gradientLayer.startPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.0, y: 0.0)
            gradientLayer.endPoint = CGPoint(x: 1.0, y: 1.0)
        }

        backgroundColor = .clear
        gradientLayer.frame = bounds
        layer.insertSublayer(gradientLayer, at: 0)
    }
```

And I'm calling this in `viewDidLoad()` like this:

```
self.viewTAGradient.applyGradientDiagonal(isVertical: false, colorArray: [UIColor.init(named: "gradient1")!, UIColor.init(named: "gradient2")!, UIColor.init(named: "gradient3")!])
```

I looked for some solutions and even tried to call it like this but this also didn't work:

```
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
        
        self.viewTAGradient.applyGradientDiagonal(isVertical: false, colorArray: [UIColor.init(named: "gradient1")!, UIColor.init(named: "gradient2")!, UIColor.init(named: "gradient3")!])
        
    }
```

Edit: New Update:
the issue is with all the gradients on iPhone 13 pro max. I copied some codes from internet for gradients and created new view controller with just one view of fixed height stuck to top and all shifted to left side on 13 pro max. works fine on other devices though. here's the screenshots:
[image]
[image]

Can anyone help me why on one particular device its behaving like that?

Comment: Did you set up constraints on `viewTAGradient` correctly?

Comment: It should be working when you call applyGradientDiagonal(isVertical:colorArray:) inside viewDidLayoutSubviews(). It works on my machine though. Could you show more code examples like how do you set up 'viewTAGradient'?

Comment: @kyaw.monkey I added more detail.

Comment: @Sweeper I'm just calling them inside a horizontal stack of fixed height = 180. With filled equally at distance of 20 they should be created automatically. See above after edit the bgColor is applied properly but gradient won't

Comment: Check your layout constraints.... assuming your `viewTAGradient` is a standard `UIView`, does it size properly if you give it a background color instead of calling `applyGradientDiagonal()`?

Comment: @DonMag it does if I just set background normally. See above in edited..even in seperate view controller, gradient shifts to left on any ui view on iPhone 13 pro max but works fine for any other device

Answer (score 0):

There's no reason for the gradient to behave differently on an iPhone 13 Pro Max, so my guess (without seeing your complete layout) would be related to constraints or when you're actually calling `applyGradientDiagonal()`.

You may find it much easier to get reliable results by subclassing `UIView` and putting the gradient code inside `layoutSubview()`.

Here's a simple example:

```
class MyGradientView: UIView {
    
    var colorArray: [UIColor] = [] {
        didSet {
            setNeedsLayout()
        }
    }
    var vertical: Bool = true {
        didSet {
            setNeedsLayout()
        }
    }
    
    static override var layerClass: AnyClass {
        return CAGradientLayer.self
    }
    
    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
        guard let layer = layer as? CAGradientLayer else { return }
        layer.colors = colorArray.map({ $0.cgColor })
        if vertical {
            // top-down gradient
            layer.startPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.5, y: 0.0)
            layer.endPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.5, y: 1.0)
        } else {
            // diagonal gradient
            layer.startPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.0, y: 0.0)
            layer.endPoint = CGPoint(x: 1.0, y: 1.0)
        }
    }

}
```

and an example view controller to demonstrate:

```
class GradientTestViewController: UIViewController {
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        let stack = UIStackView()
        stack.axis = .vertical
        stack.spacing = 8
        stack.distribution = .fillEqually
        
        let colorPairs: [[UIColor]] = [
            [.blue, .cyan],
            [.red, .yellow],
            [.blue, .yellow, .red],
        ]
        
        // 3 pairs of gradient views
        colorPairs.forEach { colors in
            let hstack = UIStackView()
            hstack.spacing = 8
            hstack.distribution = .fillEqually

            var v = MyGradientView()
            v.colorArray = colors
            v.vertical = true
            hstack.addArrangedSubview(v)
            
            v = MyGradientView()
            v.colorArray = colors
            v.vertical = false
            hstack.addArrangedSubview(v)
            
            stack.addArrangedSubview(hstack)
        }
        
        // a pair of plain, solid color views for comparison
        let hstack = UIStackView()
        hstack.spacing = 8
        hstack.distribution = .fillEqually
        
        var v = UIView()
        v.backgroundColor = .systemRed
        hstack.addArrangedSubview(v)
        v = UIView()
        v.backgroundColor = .systemBlue
        hstack.addArrangedSubview(v)
        
        stack.addArrangedSubview(hstack)
        
        stack.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        view.addSubview(stack)
        let g = view.safeAreaLayoutGuide
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            stack.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.topAnchor, constant: 20.0),
            stack.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.leadingAnchor, constant: 20.0),
            stack.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.trailingAnchor, constant: -20.0),
            stack.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.bottomAnchor, constant: -20.0),
        ])
        
        // outline the stack view
        //  so we can see its frame
        let outlineView = UIView()
        outlineView.backgroundColor = .clear
        outlineView.layer.borderColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
        outlineView.layer.borderWidth = 3
        outlineView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        view.addSubview(outlineView)
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            outlineView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: stack.topAnchor, constant: -2.0),
            outlineView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: stack.leadingAnchor, constant: -2.0),
            outlineView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: stack.trailingAnchor, constant: 2.0),
            outlineView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: stack.bottomAnchor, constant: 2.0),
        ])
    }
    
}
```

The result of running that code:

[image]

[image]